# Is there any way for a thread to get a notification when another thread stops?

Tags: python

In Python (2 and 3), is there any way for a thread to get notified whenever another thread stops?

My use case is: I'm creating a singleton thread in a module, which is to be imported by *any* other module, and I want this thread to stop when the application ends (i.e. when all threads except this one are stopped), without the user explicitly calling a `stop()` function in my module.

In other words, I want to detect the end of a multithreaded Python application from a given thread.

Comment: Couldn't you just set a flag?

Comment: em... sound like you want to make it a daemon thread,

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: interesting. Indeed daemon threads seem to be appropriate here. What if I want my thread to be the last daemon thread alive?

Comment: why you care about the order? they will die improperly anyway.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: I guess I didn't read this: _Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown._

Comment: yup. so what behavior do you want?

Comment: The behavior of daemon threads. This was what I was looking for, even though it doesn't exactly answer my original question. You should post an answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Thanks anyway.